# Is there a way to tell which to tell what the hostname where a binary was compiled is using gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb

Upon loading a binary in gdb I can use `info sources` to see paths for source files. They are absolute paths though but not sure which server the binary was built on. Is this information available at all in the binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not unless you put it there at build time.  Some projects do this, but there are no standards.